# How to check if a program is running by its name with Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, process, qt-creator, qprocess

How to check if a program is running, by its name, with Qt (C++).

Will `QProcess::pid` do the job? I don't know how to use it. Please suggest.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422145/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not) seems to fit your needs as long as you have the object.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to use QProcess::state(), like that ? QProcess::state("chrome.exe"); ??

Comment: Presumably you can get a `QProcess` object by the process name using some function and then call it on that.

Comment: Can you give an exemple please ? and thanks you very much for yours answers :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632594/get-all-running-processes-info-using-qprocess) could help, I guess. I haven't seen anything to get a process by name or to get a list of all running processes through use of a Qt function.

Comment: If you are trying to see if a particular program, *not started from a QProcess*, is running, I don't think you can do this in Qt. But if you let us know on what platform(s) this needs to work, there is certainly a non-portable way of doing it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know QProcess won't allow you to do that (unless you've spawned the process yourself) and in fact nothing in Qt will. However Win32 API provides a way to achieve what you want through `EnumProcesses` function and a complete example of how to use it is provided at Microsoft website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623.aspx

To get you need replace PrintProcessNameAndID with the following function:

```
bool matchProcessName( DWORD processID, std::string processName)
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
             &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }

    // Compare process name with your string        
    bool matchFound = !_tcscmp(szProcessName, processName.c_str() );

    // Release the handle to the process.    
    CloseHandle( hProcess );

    return matchFound;
}
```

Comment: +1 to compensate for the downvote; not sure why this was downvoted. I was going to include a link to the same page in my response. This is certainly the official way to do it.

Answer (score 11):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be to just check the output of `tasklist`, something like:

```
bool isRunning(const QString &process) {
  QProcess tasklist;
  tasklist.start(
        "tasklist",
        QStringList() << "/NH" 
                      << "/FO" << "CSV" 
                      << "/FI" << QString("IMAGENAME eq %1").arg(process));
  tasklist.waitForFinished();
  QString output = tasklist.readAllStandardOutput();
  return output.startsWith(QString("\"%1").arg(process));
}
```

Using `EnumProcesses` is probably a better way (i.e. more "pure"; certainly more performant), but this may be "good enough" as long as this isn't being called in a big loop or something. The same idea could also be ported to other platforms as well, although obviously the command tool and parsing logic would be different.

Answer (score 0):

pid() is obsolete. Here is the statement from Qt

"*This function is obsolete. It is provided to keep old source code working. **We strongly advise against using it in new code.**
Use processId() instead.
Returns the native process identifier for the running process, if available. If no process is currently running, 0 is returned."*

Sorry, the following code is for me to find the process ID based on the process name. However, you can use it to check if a process is still running. I hope this help.

```
QProcess theProcess;
QString theProgramm("pgrep") // or pidof, or any system commands you prefer.
QStringList theArgument = QStringList() << processName // processName must be QString
QByteArray theOutput

theProcess.start(theProgram, theArgument);
theProcess.waitForReadyRead();
 theOutput = theprocess.readAllStandardOutput();
theProcess.terminated();
theProcess.waitForFinished();
theProcess.kill();

return (theOutput.isEmpty()) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 //How to Run App
 bool ok = QProcess::startDetached("C:\\TTEC\\CozxyLogger\\CozxyLogger.exe");
 qDebug() <<  "Run = " << ok;


 //How to Kill App
 system("taskkill /im CozxyLogger.exe /f");
 qDebug() << "Close";
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This is not the answer to the question "How to check **if a program is running...**. But thanks for your input anyhow.