# how to detect a process is already running in memory in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am beginner to QT. I am working on a QT application. I have to run a list of processes if it is not running in the memory. The problem is how can i detect a process is already running in the memory or not. For example i have a process name `abc` than how can i detect it is already running. Something i need is like

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
int status = p->start("check if abc is running or not");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422145/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not

Comment: @Arun i searched for it will show if the QProcess instance is running a process i need to find if the process 'abc' is running in the memory where `abc` is the process name

Comment: ah I see, may be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632594/get-all-running-processes-info-using-qprocess

Comment: thanks arun my issue is solved

Comment: Glad that helped! most welcome Noor :-)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use the QMutex.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutex.html

Comment: Did you read the question?